# How to arrange many UIView in a pattern targeting different sized displays

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, optimization, uiview

**Aim:**

Targeting different iPhone and iPad sized displays, I’m wanting to arrange many small square `UIView` in a pattern. Once arranged in place, I want to be able to control each `UIView` so that I can manipulate each one, for example, move and scale each individually.

One approach would be to place many small `UIView` manually on the Storyboard (Image 1), making sure to have enough small `UIView` to arrange in a pattern on the largest iPad screen, and then connect them all up in code. For example

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView001: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var myView002: UIView!
...
...
@IBOutlet weak var myView144: UIView!
```

But, the above approach seems very complex and not elegant.

> **Question:**
>
> How can I dynamically (and elegantly) create many small `UIView`, that
>   can be arranged in a pattern to fit the smallest iPhone screen and the
>   largest iPad screen, that can be manipulated in Swift code?

**Image 1:**

[image]

Comment: How about creating views programmatically and using `addSubview`?

Comment: This sounds interesting, but how can I create a `UIView` programmatically, and how would I go about positioning it and then manipulating it, for example, to move or scale it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to create a subview and add it to your current view:

```
let subview = UIView()
subview.backgroundColor = .black
subview.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
self.view.addSubview(subview)
```

Another way to init multiple subviews, e.g., 10:

```
let subviews = (0 ..< 10).map { _ in UIView() }
for i in 0..<10 {
    subviews[i].frame = CGRect(x: 10 * i, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)
}
```

You need to identify the frame, calculate the distance and views' size, and add them to your current view.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the idea of the first method, but the second one is not really clear to me. Would you be able to expand on the explanation of "init multiple subviews" and how to identify each subview that is created?

Comment: The logic is similar to the former, but it should be more convenient to use. I updated my answer.

Comment: Many thanks. This is really helpful. Is that Swift 2 or 3?

Comment: @user4806509 It's swift 3.